# seen getdate() to go 30 days ahead

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is how every time I try to set date to 30 days ahead into the `getdate()+30` then it will in no way indicate the 30 days into the database.

I have done this:

```
string id = Session["id"].ToString();
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BrugerATrydato", id);
    cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE brugere SET trydato = getdate()+30 WHERE Id = @BrugerATrydato;";

    conn1.Open();
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn1.Close();
```

Problem is: into the database will in no way some date forward at all. I have also tried with `getdate()`

question is if I do something wrong here since it will not give dato'en?

Comment: Plz share your table structure.

Comment: I would recommend explicitly defining the datatype of your parameters instead of letting .net determine the type. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood exactly what you're asking. But is your problem that  you can't get SQL Server to give you a date 30 days in the future? If so, try this:

```
Update brugere Set trydato = DateAdd(Day,30,GetDate())
```

Comment: Okay, but you help me to get that problem solved, I hope you will help to give me +1 and I give you a +1 when I have the chance.

and it works and it has given me to d 19-3-2015 Danish date / hour